# Prevent new ARN Version generation on lambda layer update

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I have created a layer which contains some codes that can be used by multiple lambda function.
Something like this:

```js
module.exports = {
    "INVALID_RFC": {"code": "111", "message": "RFC Code is invalid"}
}
```

The problem is that whenever I make some update on the layer, AWS genertate a new version for it. Due to this, I have to manually update the version in all of the lambda. I understand its importance and use-case, but I want to prevent it. Manullay updating the Lambda everytime is too much time taking.

Comment: Hi Shadab, I would strongly recommend that you automate your deployments. If you use tools like Terraform or CloudFormation, you can automatically set the ARN of the new layer version in your Lambdas with every deployment. As far as I know, you can not disable this behaviour.

Comment: I'm using serverless for deployment which i think uses CloudFormation. I'll have to check out that one.

Comment: If you use `serverless` already I would think they have something to reference layer versions in a Lambdas definition.